# PHP Displaying an embed before a certain date only

Tags: javascript, php, date, time, disqus

I am trying to display a Disqus commenting embed on a website, but I only want it to display the embed if it's before 2nd February 2014 UK time.

EDIT: For clarity, It should always display the embed before the 2nd Feb 2014 on any date but never after.

The PHP code I have is:

```
<?php if (time() <= strtotime('2014-02-02 00:00:00')) {   ?>
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var disqus_shortname = 'mysite'; // required: replace example with your forum shortname
(function() {
var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
})();
</script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="http://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
<a href="http://disqus.com" class="dsq-brlink">comments powered by <span class="logo-disqus">Disqus</span></a>
<?php } else {
//do something else
}?>
```

However, it doesn't seem to be displaying on posts. I have replaced 'my site'. This is just for an example.

Comment: given that it's Feb 3rd now, your discus code would never get output anyways...

Comment: we already passed 2nd February dude.. The universal truth is that day will  not come again... :(

Comment: Perhaps I should clarify. It should always display the embed before the 2nd Feb 2014 on any date but never after.